# Switching python environment does not apply to active terminal unless a new terminal is opened

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using a conda and venv python environment for developement in visual studio code on windows 10.

When I switch between environements, the programs run fine but in the terminal the changes are not reflected unless I create a new terminal. Is this intended or a bug? Is it possible to automate the switching of the environements in the terminal

Comment: _When I switch between environements_ Show us the exact commands you used to create the environments, and the exact commands you use to switch environments.

Comment: Are you switching environments **inside of vs code**?  Of course that is not going to affect a terminal window...

Comment: Please be more precise what you mean by "changes are not reflected unless".... 
There are changes in windows terminal that are not reflected until you open another terminal, esp. changes in environment variables, and some things in conda are changed by environment variables, but in generals, changes done to a conda env should be available in other termianl  instances. So make clearer what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch the interpreter, the pyhton extension will use the new interpreter to run the code, and the interpreter version will be displayed in the lower right corner of the interface.

The problem you may encounter is that the terminal does not change after switching the interpreter, but the code actually executed uses the newly selected interpreter.

[image]

Comment: The code runs in the selecte environment. However, as the change is not reflected in the existing terminal I have accidentally installed packages in the old environment several times and messed it up. Is it possible to swtich the terminal also without closing and opening a new terminal?

Comment: You can manually activate the environment by typing commands in the terminal. for example: `path/to/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`(venv), `conda activate base`(conda)

Comment: My doubts are cleared. It is not a bug and intended behaviour. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature in VS Code. You were in environment A, so then you switch to environment B, and that becomes the new environment from then on. As for the automation I am unsure. I like my environment like this, so I can have my frontend code in one terminal, and backend code in the other.